# Finding correlations from multiple irregular time series

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have data from different sources that is currently in multiple data frames. They generally look something like:

```
TimeStamp (MS Detail Converted with strptime), Field1, Field2, Field3
```

In all cases the Time Stamps are irregular, and the fields are either character data or int data.

There are three types of correlations I would like to be able to do with this data (using the term loosely). In all cases these will sometimes be from the same source, and other times from different sources:

1. Numeric to Numeric
2. Numeric to Categorical (string). I am not sure of the proper term for this, but if field1 where to have values like A, B, and C, how might find if field2 has higher numbers than B is more likely to be the value of field1

The end goal is not only to test for correlations, but also to be able to discover them. I realize this is a pretty vague / big area. Mostly looking for basic examples, or point in the right direction of how to transform my data into format that will let me do these things.

Comment: Did you consider aggregating the data to normalize the times? For example if your time-stamps are in seconds, you can aggregate them into hourly observations, by taking means for example. This will solve the irregularity problem. You can then proceed calculating correlations in the usual way.

Comment: @mpiktas: Looked into that a little. Two areas of confusion with this for me. I have about 25 items a second so I would maybe want to aggregate to something like 1/10th a second (is that possible R?). Also, since a lot of the fields are categorical loosing even one of those categorical items would make it so I can't see the correlation. Maybe I would somehow need to correlate the numeric to every possible combination of category count per 1/10th second?

Comment: @Kyle Brandt: R can probably handle that kind of aggregation, check out the `xts` package.  Why not just count the number of occurrences of each category for your categorical variables?

Comment: @Zach: I have been playing with zoo/xts a little. For the occurrences of categorical data I have been doing that manually with stuff like `plot(table(cut(categoryA_subset_value_is_B$TimeStamp, "Secs"...` and then visually looking for correlations. But not quite sure how to do ask things like the following R: "What value of categoryA best correlates with Numeric Q? with a fudge factor of X seconds?" I believe this cross correlation, but really just learning stats (if you can't tell :-P)

Comment: @Kyle, If the correlation is there, you will not lose it by aggregating. For categorical values, Zach is right, just use counts, then for each time period $t$ you will have a observation of multinomial distribution, i.e. vector of counts of categories. When you have such normalized time-series, the answer to your last question is much clearer. After aggregating instead of one categorical variable A you several  where variable will hold the counts for the respective category values. You then can just calculate ...

Comment: ... simple correlations of these count variables with the numeric Q, with any fudge time factor you want. Then pick the highest correlation and this will be your highest correlating value of category A. This indeed will be cross-correlations.

Comment: @Kyle, the first thing I would check is how to appropriately calculate the correlation between count variable and the numeric variable. Another thing is stationarity, if you have a lot of observations and they are trending, then the correlations can be spurious.

Comment: If you can give a synthetic (or even real) sample of the data, it would help a bit in giving an answer.  It doesn't have to be your real data set, but if you can cobble an analogy to something else, that would be good. An example might be from web traffic data, customer behavior, marketing, etc.  I'd rather given an approximately correct answer in the right direction than a correct answer in the wrong direction.  :)